# Unicode character in listings

Tags: listings, unicode

I need to insert character "[└](http://unicode-table.com/en/2514/)" in `lstlisting` and compile it with `pdflatex`. Other unsupported characters like "ě" I am handling via literate option in `\lstset{}`. Is there any way how to insert it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to approximate it using math mode. That character looks a lot like `$^{\mathsf{L}}$`, so it's possible to just use that in the literate option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\large\ttfamily,
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    literate=%
        {á}{{\'a}}1
        {ě}{{\v{e}}}1
        {í}{{\'i}}1
        {└}{{\(^{\mathsf L}\)}}1
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
Jsou nadáni rozumem a svědomím a mají spolu jednat v duchu bratrství.

Here is the character: └.
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Here's what the output looks like:

[image]

Comment: With `\usepackage{pmboxdraw}` you can say `{└}{{\textSFii}}1` in the `literal` list.

Comment: @egreg: Package pmboxdraw has more useful characters. That's what I am looking for. Thanks!